# 2 Thessalonians 2: Is the day of Lord before or after antichrist takes his seat in the temple of God?

Tags: 2-thessalonians, eschatology

2 Thessalonians 2:1-4

> 1Now concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our being
> gathered together to him, we ask you, brothers,a 2not to be quickly
> shaken in mind or alarmed, either by a spirit or a spoken word, or a
> letter seeming to be from us, to the effect that the day of the Lord
> has come. 3Let no one deceive you in any way. For that day will not
> come, unless the rebellion comes first, and the man of lawlessnessb is
> revealed, the son of destruction,c 4who opposes and exalts himself
> against every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his
> seat in the temple of God, proclaiming himself to be God.

Does the day of the Lord start before or after antichrist takes his seat in the temple of God?

Answer (score 0):

2 Thess 2:1-4

> 1Now concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our being
> gathered together to him, we ask you, brothers,a 2not to be quickly
> shaken in mind or alarmed, either by a spirit or a spoken word, or a
> letter seeming to be from us, to the effect that the day of the Lord
> has come. 3Let no one deceive you in any way. For that day will not
> come, unless the rebellion comes first, and the man of lawlessnessb is
> revealed, the son of destruction,c 4who opposes and exalts himself
> against every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his
> seat in the temple of God, proclaiming himself to be God.

**For that day...**
There's going to be a day: for now call it "that day"

**... will not come, unless ...**
And *before* "that day", what's going to happen?

**... the rebellion comes first, and the man of lawlessnessb is revealed, the son of destruction,c 4who opposes and exalts himself against every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his seat in the temple of God, proclaiming himself to be God.**
The man of lawlessness takes his seat in the temple of God

Sequence:

1. man of lawlessness takes his seat in the temple of God
2. "that day"

What is "that day"?

> 1Now concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our being
> gathered together to him, we ask you, brothers,a 2not to be quickly
> shaken in mind or alarmed, either by a spirit or a spoken word, or a
> letter seeming to be from us, to the effect that **the day of the Lord
> has come**.

The day of the Lord

Sequence:

1. man of lawlessness takes his seat in the temple of God
2. day of the Lord